# Trouble booting windows on a dual booted machine with Linux

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I'm currently experiencing some problems with windows 10 on a dual-booted machine with ubuntu 18.04.

For some reason, I cannot boot windows anymore as it's stuck on "attempting repairs". I've managed to diagnose that the problem is likely due to the partition I have on windows. The file system is of the form "bitlocker" and I cannot run chdsk nor sfc/scannow to fix the issue.

I can access the advanced options on windows and there I have the "reset this pc" button which would probably get rid of all files in the system which would be fine as I don't have anything I would need there any more.

However I'm not sure what would happen if I proceed to reset the pc as I have dual booted the machine and ubuntu runs fine. I would be also be fine with ubuntu being erased, but I have slight concerns about what will happen if I just proceed to reset the pc?

Here is a screenshot of gparted with the partitions. They look fine to me except this red flag on the microsoft reserved partition. Any ideas what might be causing that?

The error on GParted states that

Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:

- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/nvme0n1p2 is missing

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqdy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :
1- booting a Windows based Live USB like ‍`WinPE 10-8 Sergei Strelec` and unlock the bitlocker drive in order to take the backup of files and/or repairing the OS / Partition.
2- Using tools like `Dislocker` to unlock bitlocker drives in Linux (which maybe risky).

Comment: What should I achieve by unlocking the bitlocker drives?

Comment: Backing up files and any sensitive information in case there is no success in booting OS and you have no other choice other than formatting the drive.